# Excel Hyperlinks do not go to correct location

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-2019

**NOTE: LINKS ARE FAKE.**

My hyperlinks that should be taking me to a specific link will only take me to the general page.

Example:
Should be https://example.company.com/webpage?search_searchText=12345678
Directs me to https://example.company.com/home

Additional Notes:

- This issue only started happening once I started using Excel 2019.
- Confirmed that it does work for others in Excel 2016
- I am using the =hyperlink() formula
- If I hover over the link it will show
  https://example.company.com/webpage?search_searchText=12345678.
- If I
  copy and paste the hyperlink into my email that accepts hyperlink, I can click on the link and it will work.
- Same thing happens in Microsoft Edge as well
- I am logged into the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused by a missing registry entry.
The key is (HKLM)>SOFTWARE>Office>9.0>Common>Internet

Values should be:
Name | Type | Data
(Default) | REG_SZ | (value not set)
ForceShellExecute | REG_DWORD | 0x00000001(1)

After added this registry entry I found that I can now open the linked when clicked in Excel.